# AngularJS email validation using input with dynamic name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the code below where I'm validating the email input using AngularJS. This is in an ng-repeat and I'm tracking the person this pertains to using 'data.affiliateSelect.cusomter_no'.

I'm appending that customer_no to the name of the email input in order make sure they all have unique names. **How can I reference this name within the span.error-msg ngShow expression?** I've tried a few different ways with no success.

Thanks in advance.

```
<form name="registrantForm" ng-submit="submitRegistrantForm()" novalidate>    
<div class="session-registrant-field field-email" ng-if="data.affiliateSelect.ask_email == 'Y'">
   <label for="">Email
      <span class="error-msg" ng-show="registrantForm.$submitted || registrantForm.(email+'-'+data.affiliateSelect.customer_no).$touched">
      <span ng-show="registrantForm.(email+'-'+data.affiliateSelect.customer_no).$error.required">Please provide your email.</span>
      <span ng-show="registrantForm.(email+'-'+data.affiliateSelect.customer_no).$error.email">Please enter a valid email.</span>
      </span>
   </label>
   <input type="email" name="email-{{data.affiliateSelect.customer_no}}" id="email-{{data.affiliateSelect.customer_no}}" value"" ng-model="affiliateEmail" required>          
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
registrantForm['email-' + cartPerf.perf_no + data.affiliateSelect.customer_no].$error.required
```

above is the correct syntax that I needed to get this to work.